# Using purrr::pmap within mutate to create list-column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I understand how to use map to iterate over arguments in a df and create a new list column.

For example,

```
params <- expand.grid(param_a = c(2, 4, 6)
                  ,param_b = c(3, 6, 9)
                  ,param_c = c(50, 100)
                  ,param_d = c(1, 0)
                  )

df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::map(param_a, function(x){
      rep(5, x)
      }
    ))
```

However, how do I use the analogous syntax with pmap in the event that I want to specify more than 2 parameters?

```
df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                     ,y = param_b
                                     ,z = param_c
                                     ,u = param_d), function(x, y){
                                        rep(5,x)*y
                                     }
  )
  )
```

Error output:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: unused arguments (z = .l[[c(3, i)]], u = .l[[c(4, i)]]).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `pmap`, the first argument is a list, so you can pass it your data frame directly, and then name your arguments in your function with the same names as the columns in your data frame. You'll need `unnest()` to unpack the list elements returned by `pmap()`:

```
df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(., function(param_a, param_b, ...){
                                        rep(5, param_a) * param_b
                                     })) %>%
    tidyr::unnest()


> df.preprocessed
# A tibble: 144 x 5
   param_a param_b param_c param_d test_var
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       2       3      50       1       15
 2       2       3      50       1       15
 3       4       3      50       1       15
 4       4       3      50       1       15
 5       4       3      50       1       15
 6       4       3      50       1       15
 7       6       3      50       1       15
 8       6       3      50       1       15
 9       6       3      50       1       15
10       6       3      50       1       15
# ... with 134 more rows
```

Answer (score 7):

How about using `rowwise` and `mutate` directly without `map`:

```
my_fun <- function(param_a, param_b){
  rep(5, param_a) * param_b
}
df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = list(my_fun(param_a, param_b))) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest()
```

Comment: That’s a great answer. `rowwise` is different from `group_by`, as it unwraps list columns: `tibble(test = list(1, 2)) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(cls = class(test))` shows that `cls` is numeric, not `list`

Answer (score 2):

We could try

```
f1 <- function(x, y, ...) rep(5, x)*y

df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                 ,y = param_b
                                 ,z = param_c
                                 ,u = param_d),f1
    )
   )
df.preprocessed
# A tibble: 36 x 5
#   param_a param_b param_c param_d  test_var
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <list>
# 1       2       3      50       1 <dbl [2]>
# 2       4       3      50       1 <dbl [4]>
# 3       6       3      50       1 <dbl [6]>
# 4       2       6      50       1 <dbl [2]>
# 5       4       6      50       1 <dbl [4]>
# 6       6       6      50       1 <dbl [6]>
# 7       2       9      50       1 <dbl [2]>
# 8       4       9      50       1 <dbl [4]>
# 9       6       9      50       1 <dbl [6]>
#10       2       3     100       1 <dbl [2]>
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                            ,y = param_b
                                            ,z = param_c
                                            ,u = param_d),
                                              ~ rep(5,.x)*.y                                                
  )
  )
```

or

```
df.preprocessed <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                            ,y = param_b
                                            ,z = param_c
                                            ,u = param_d),
                                       ~ rep(5,..1)*..2                                       
  )
  )
```

The second way is more general as you can use `..3`, `..4` etc...

Comment: Thanks.  I like the ..3 ..4 syntax but it appears it only works when we're using the shortcut way of writing a formula.  I actually have a multi-line formula, and so need to use function(x, y, z, u) where you use the tilda.

Comment: I don't understand, can you share your formula ?

Comment: `df.test <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                            ,y = param_b
                                            ,z = param_c
                                            ,u = param_d),
                                       function(x,y,z,u){
                                                        rep(5,..1)*..2
                                                        }
  )
  )`

Comment: This won't work indeed, but I don't understand in which circumstances you wouldn't be able to  use the short form I proposed.

Comment: I've never had luck with using purrr's tilde shortcut whenever the formula has more than 1 line.  In my case, the formula has about 10.  Am I wrong on this?

Comment: that's why I asked you to share your formula :). On my side I have no problem inserting new lines in my formula. Maybe doucble check. It could be related to versions, then try wrapping the formula in `{}`

Comment: `df.test <- dplyr::as.tbl(params) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_var = purrr::pmap(list(x = param_a
                                            ,y = param_b
                                            ,z = param_c
                                            ,u = param_d),
                                         ~ rep(5,..1)*..2 %>%
                                         runif(min=..3, max=..4)
  )
  )`

Comment: with `function/x/y/z/u` I get the same result than with `~/..1 etc` , with some warnings in both cases, but no error