# apply/map a different function per row in a data frame with varying parameters

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a simple problem for you purrr-experts out there that has eluded my best googling efforts for some time. First, let's take a look at the nested-list data structure I'm trying to work with.

## Load packages

```
#R version 3.4.1    
library(purrr) # version 0.2.4
library(dplyr) # version 0.7.4
```

## Define functions

```
f1 <- function(a, b, c) {a + b^c}
f2 <- function(x) {x * 2}
f3 <- function(y, z) {y * z}
```

## Define parameter sets

These are to be passed through to each of `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`:

```
p1 <- data_frame(a = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8),
                 b = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 c = c(.5, 5, 1, 2, 3))
p2 <- data_frame(x = c(1, 4))
p3 <- data_frame(y = c(2, 2, 2, 3),
                 z = c(5, 4, 3, 2))
```

## Put them together into a nested dataframe

I am trying to keep my data wieldy, in a nice, neat rectangle.  The "id" variable is the function name itself (in my real data, there are hundreds of these):

```
df <- data_frame(fun_id = c('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), 
                 params = list(p1, p2, p3), 
                 funs = list(f1, f2, f3))
```

Checking the structure shows us the list-columns for `params` and `funs`:

```
print(df)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  fun_id           params   funs
   <chr>           <list> <list>
1     f1 <tibble [5 x 3]>  <fun>
2     f2 <tibble [2 x 1]>  <fun>
3     f3 <tibble [4 x 2]>  <fun>
```

## My question

Using `purrr` functions and perhaps `dplyr::mutate`, how do I get a new list-column in `df` called `results` in which each element is a list containing the outputs of executing the functions in `funs` with parameters taken from `params`, in a rowwise fashion?

I can get `pmap` to do what I want for a simple case:

```
> pmap(.l = p1, .f = f1)

[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 7

[[4]]
[1] 11

[[5]]
[1] 16
```

But I really want to do this inside a data frame to keep everything straight. The following gets me to the right structure (a data frame with a list-column for the results), but only for one row and it's not generalized:

```
> df %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(results = list(pmap(.l = params[[1]], .f = funs[[1]])))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  fun_id           params   funs    results
   <chr>           <list> <list>     <list>
1     f1 <tibble [5 x 3]>  <fun> <list [5]>
```

Thanks in advance for the help rounding out my problem!

P.S. I have looked at the following resources, but haven't found an answer yet:

[purrr::pmap with dplyr::mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705469/purrrpmap-with-dplyrmutate)

[Using purrr::pmap within mutate to create list-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531582/using-purrrpmap-within-mutate-to-create-list-column)

http://statwonk.com/purrr.html

https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/purrr.pdf

https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a convenience function in `purrr` for exactly this situation; applying a list of functions to a corresponding list of parameters! It's called `invoke_map` and can be used with `mutate` as below. I think the main advantage over `map2(~pmap())` is that if there are additional parameters to supply to any of the functions not included in `params` you can add them as named arguments in `...` instead of needing to modify `params`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- function(a, b, c) {a + b^c}
f2 <- function(x) {x * 2}
f3 <- function(y, z) {y * z}
p1 <- data_frame(
  a = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8),
  b = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  c = c(.5, 5, 1, 2, 3)
)
p2 <- data_frame(x = c(1, 4))
p3 <- data_frame(
  y = c(2, 2, 2, 3),
  z = c(5, 4, 3, 2)
)
df <- data_frame(
  fun_id = c("f1", "f2", "f3"),
  params = list(p1, p2, p3),
  funs = list(f1, f2, f3)
)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(results = invoke_map(.f = funs, .x = params))
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   fun_id params           funs   results  
#>   <chr>  <list>           <list> <list>   
#> 1 f1     <tibble [5 x 3]> <fn>   <dbl [5]>
#> 2 f2     <tibble [2 x 1]> <fn>   <dbl [2]>
#> 3 f3     <tibble [4 x 2]> <fn>   <dbl [4]>
df2$results
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  3  5  7 11 16
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 8
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 10  8  6  6
```

Created on 2018-07-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Next time I need to "invoke" a function with purrr, I'll remember the invoke_map approach. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` and apply the `pmap` function for each row.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(result = map2(params, funs, ~pmap(.l = .x, .f = .y)))
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   fun_id params           funs   result    
#   <chr>  <list>           <list> <list>    
# 1 f1     <tibble [5 x 3]> <fn>   <list [5]>
# 2 f2     <tibble [2 x 1]> <fn>   <list [2]>
# 3 f3     <tibble [4 x 2]> <fn>   <list [4]>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  It definitely solves the problem (and was first), but I like the simplicity and the purpose-built nature of the invoke_map solution provided by Calum.

Comment: @vergilcw I agree Calum's answer is better for this.